# Real roots for exponential-polynomial equations

Tags: exponential-function, roots

I am trying to find the number of real roots of an equation such as

$k_1 x e^x-e^{k_2 x}-k_3x+k_4=0.$

Setting the first derivative equals to zero is analytically unsolvable, unfortunately. Do you know perhaps a useful tool for this type of equations?

Thank you!

Comment: [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @Kenny, that's probably overkill if OP only wants to count them rather than to actually find them.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked.

Comment: More than this, Newton is of virtually no use for root isolation.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Plotting the function in Mathematica consistently gives me a root at zero and one > 0. I would like to formally prove this is indeed the case. I can prove the limit for x->0 to be 0 and for x->infinity to be -infinity. That's as far as I got.

Comment: "consistently a root at zero": do you mean that $0-1-0+k_4=0$ ???

Comment: No, sorry, I had forgotten a parameter:
$k_1 x e^x-k_5e^{k_2 x}-k_3x+k_4=0.$ Then $k_4-k_5=0$. Shouldn't matter for the solution strategy I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first derivative equation is

$$k_1(x+1)e^x-k_2e^{k_2x}-k_3=0$$

and the second one,

$$k_1(x+2)e^x-k_2^2e^{k_2x}=0.$$

The solution(s) of the latter can be formulated in terms of the Lambert function $W$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Examples

The roots of the second derivative correspond to the extrema of the first derivative, which allow to to detect all changes of sign. Then you refine the roots with a bracketing method such as regula falsi.

These give you the extrema of the initial function, the changes of sign and then the roots.

This is an indirect approach not amenable to analytical study, by it guarantees the correct enumeration of the solutions.