# Roots of a polynomial in $x$ and $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, exponential-function, roots

I have equations of the following form:

$$(p_1(y) + p_2(y) x)^2 + p_3(y) = 0$$

Where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $y = e^x$ and the $p_i$ are polynomials with real coefficients.

Is there any way to say something about the set of roots to this equation?

Specifically:

- some reasonable bound $B$ such that the zeros are $|x| \le B$
- some bound on the number of roots

I'm trying to write a program to solve the equation numerically (analytical is clearly hopeless), but not sure how to proceed without some info about the roots.

If I knew the roots to an $n$th derivative of the equation, I could work my way "up" and find the roots of the original equation too, but not sure if that helps.

Some related problems I've looked at:

- [Real roots for exponential-polynomial equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842654/real-roots-for-exponential-polynomial-equations)
- [Solving a polynomial with a natural log included with other terms for zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967013/solving-a-polynomial-with-a-natural-log-included-with-other-terms-for-zero)

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the degree of $p_3$?

Comment: It might be worthy to check the derivative - when is it eventually positive/negative. Note that
$$
\frac {\text d}{\text dx} p(y) = yp'(y)
$$
which doesn't have the free term. However, it's harder to solve the derivative for $x$, as you lose the square.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $x$ results in

$$x = \dfrac{-p_1(y)\pm\sqrt{-p_3(y)}}{p_2(y)}=\dfrac{-p_1(\exp(x))\pm\sqrt{-p_3(\exp(x))}}{p_2(\exp(x))}=\Phi(x).$$

You might be able to make some statements about the roots if you are able to check the conditions for the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: How about putting $\log y$ instead of $x$? And asymptotically 
$$
(-p_1 \pm \sqrt p_3)/p_2 \approx \text{const} \cdot y ^\wedge [\max(\deg p_1, \  1/2 \ \deg p_3) - \deg p_2],
$$
for large $y$ unless $\deg p_1 = \: 1/2 \ \deg p_3$ and leading coefficients of $p_1$ and $p_3$ are appropriate. For small $y$, consider $\log (1/y)$ and polynomials in $1/y$ (degrees will possibly change).